# Files not showing in Finder, Mid-2014 Macbook Pro, OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, finder, invisible-files

Recently my Finder crashed when I was doing some Terminal work, and I ended up having to force-quit it.

Since then, my Finder isn't showing any of my files or folders, apart from the ones on my desktop. I can see them in Terminal, but neither the icons nor the filenames are showing up in the Finder window.

Finder is now also permanently taking up 99.9% CPU according to Activity Monitor.
I've refreshed com.apple.IconServices, and relaunched Finder multiple times, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody have a fix? Thank you!

Comment: Have you rebooted the Mac?

Comment: Multiple times, doesn't seem to affect it. I logged into the guest account as well and it had the same problem. Very confused!

Answer (score 1):

OK so you have verified the issue on another account so it is not a user-specific preference file that is damaged causing this issue. So something unknown likely caused some damage to the Finder itself.

Can you boot into safe mode? (that would be hold SHIFT while booting) If so I would do that and download and install the latest Combo Updater for your current version of O/S X.

Failing that I would boot into recovery mode and just reinstall your O/S. do **not** wipe the HD (though you might want to use disk utility to repair the drive and permissions first) and just install over what is already there.

Re-installation should not wipe any of your files, just repair the O/S, allowing you to boot the system, apply updates and get back to work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Steve, much appreciated.  
I've booted into Safe Mode, as well as reinstalled OS X - both don't seem to solve the problem.  
In the end I gave up and rang up AppleCare - I was elevated to a Senior Advisor who told me they didn't have a solution, and marked my bug as high priority to be passed onto Apple's software engineers for a fix.  
Hopefully they'll come up with something in the next few days!